# Flexslider Item Width/Height

Tags: jquery, flexslider, woothemes

What I'm looking to achieve with this is for the slider to move the correct distance for each slide where each may have a different size. So is there a way to evaluate the next/previous slide width/height each time the user clicks to move the slider - in this case up or down.